# Visual Studio 2017 y la última actualización

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

> Couldn't process file resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file.

Me ocurre esto cuando compilo mi proyecto y no lo puedo ejecutar, esto ocurre desde la última actualización de visual studio. Alguien sabe cómo resolverlo?.

Answer (score -1):

Por alguna razón, tu archivo `.resx` se ha marcado como bloqueado por el sistema. Lo que debes hacer es buscar el archivo en el navegador de windows, botón derecho, propiedades y probablemente veas algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es así, pulsa el check que pone `Desbloquear` y después en `Aplicar` y `Aceptar`.